# mpg123 library with Qt

Tags: qt, mp3, phonon

I want add support for playback of mp3 file in my Qt app for embedded linux.

I'm not able to use phonon in Qt. After adding QT += phonon in .pro file it gives me the following error during compilation :
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/../../../../lib/libphonon.so: undefined reference to `QWidget::x11Event(_XEvent*)'

/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/../../../../lib/libphonon.so: undefined reference to `QDataStream::QDataStream(QByteArray*, int)'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

So now i'm thinking of using the mpg123 lib for decoding mp3 files.

I need help integrating the library in Qt. I've never used a pure c++ library in Qt before so i don't have much idea on how to integrate it.

Comment: Have you tried "QT += core gui phonon"?

Comment: Its not working. Same error. If i write - 'QT += core gui' then it compiles but as soon as I add phonon to it gives error.

I think Qt is not able to locate the actual library path of 'phonon'

I have installed the libphonon-dev package version '4:4.3.1-4ubuntu1' from the synaptic package manager.

I'm using Qt 4.7.1 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey all !! Finally I figured it out !!

```
int MP3Player::Init(const char *pFileName)

{

    mpg123_init();

    m_mpgHandle = mpg123_new(0, 0);
    if(mpg123_open(m_mpgHandle, pFileName) != MPG123_OK)
    {
        qFatal("Cannot open %s: %s", pFileName, mpg123_strerror(m_mpgHandle));
        return 0;
    }
}

int MP3Player::Play()

{

    unsigned char *audio;
    int mc;
    size_t bytes;
    qWarning("play_frame");


    static unsigned char* arr = 0;

    /* The first call will not decode anything but return MPG123_NEW_FORMAT! */

    mc = mpg123_decode_frame(m_mpgHandle, &m_framenum, &audio, &bytes);

    if(bytes)
    {

        /* Normal flushing of data, includes buffer decoding. */

        /*This function is my already implemented audio class which uses ALSA to output decoded audio to Sound Card*/
        if (m_audioPlayer.Play(arr,bytes) < (int)bytes) 
        {
            qFatal("Deep trouble! Cannot flush to my output anymore!");
        }

    }
    /* Special actions and errors. */
    if(mc != MPG123_OK)
    {
        if(mc == MPG123_ERR)
        {
            qFatal("...in decoding next frame: %s", mpg123_strerror(m_mpgHandle));
            return CSoundDecoder::EOFStream;

        }
        if(mc == MPG123_DONE)
        {
            return CSoundDecoder::EOFStream;
        }
        if(mc == MPG123_NO_SPACE)
        {
            qFatal("I have not enough output space? I didn't plan for this.");
            return CSoundDecoder::EOFStream;
        }
        if(mc == MPG123_NEW_FORMAT)
        {
            long iFrameRate;
            int encoding;
            mpg123_getformat(m_mpgHandle, &iFrameRate, &m_iChannels, &encoding);

            m_iBytesPerChannel = mpg123_encsize(encoding);

            if (m_iBytesPerChannel == 0)
                qFatal("bytes per channel is 0 !!");

            m_audioPlayer.Init(m_iChannels , iFrameRate , m_iBytesPerChannel);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't mention integration with Qt at all.

Comment: Well, Qt is just like a additional library for C++. So, as this code is in C++ it will work with Qt.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get mpg123 working with your QT project you try following steps:

1.download and install mpg123: from the folder where you extracted it to (e.g /home/mpg123-1.13.0/) run ./configure and then "sudo make install"

2.if there are no errors put this line to your *.pro file

```
LIBS += /usr/local/lib/libmpg123.so
```

3.then code below should run fine for you:

```
#include "mpg123.h"
#include <QDebug>

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    const char **decoders = mpg123_decoders();
    while (*decoders != NULL)
    {
        qDebug() << *decoders;
        decoders++;
    }
}
```

alternatively you can call mpg123 via system call:

```
system("mpg123 /home/test.mp3");
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: Or just install libmpg123-devel to replace step 1.

Comment: Hey serge_gubenko, thanks for the reply !!! :) ... Its working but I want to properly use the API and want to pass the file name to the mpg123 library function call instead of making a system function call.

Comment: To be specific i want to know which function should I call for just playing the mp3 ? Actually the library is not properly documented and I don't have much experience in working with third party libraries.

Comment: mpg123 is open source, take a look at what main function in mpg123.c does

Comment: I'm trying to trace the main function on mpg123.c for a long time. I figured the following argc is the argument count and argv is the argument value. So I have to pass the file name to argv[0]. Right ?

Comment: Where does this function point to ?? -> fname = get_next_file()